# no search_api_solr results when search term ends with number

Tags: views, search

I have search_api_solr with views (I use as external Solr server https://hostedapachesolr.com. )

There is this strange issue:

1/ When I search for **951**, there are correct results

2/ When I search for **V951L**, correct results

***3/ BUT ... when I search for *V951*: there are NO results at all ...***

This weird behavior stays the same, even when I alter the "views" settings or the search_api_solr settings.
It's like the system is confused that the search term begins with a letter and ends on numbers.

Does anybody knows how to fix this ?

Best regards

Comment: Please post your solution when you solve. I run into various odd things with search_api_solr too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this.

Go into The solr server configuration - assuming it's named 'solr'
/admin/config/search/search-api/server/solr/edit

In Advanced, see if "Targeted content domain" is set to scientific. And see the description next to it to see why I'm thinking this might be your issue.

Save. You'll probably need to re-export your config zips and definitely need to clear and re-index.